# SOAP TCP Tunnel/Monitor alternatives

Tags: java, soap

I've been using TCP Tunnel/Monitor for examining the payload data as it's passed over the network. Functionally, it's fine, but it's really ugly and I would have thought there would be more features available. Has anyone seen any better alternatives out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

soapUI has traffic [monitoring](http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-Recording/monitor-reference.html).